# The largest area of a polygon inscribed in a circle

Tags: real-analysis

> Let polygons with $n$ angles. This polygons are inscribed in a circle with a radius of $1$.Is there one that has the largest area among them?

**My try:**
Our polygons we can divided into $n$ isosceles triangles. 
These trangles have surface area: $$ S_{n}=\frac{1 \cdot 1 \cdot \sin(\alpha_{n})}{2} $$So polygons have surface area:$$S=S_{1}+S_{2}+...+S_{n}=\frac{\sin(\alpha_{1})+\sin(\alpha_{2})+...\sin(\alpha_{n})}{2}$$That's why:$$S'(\alpha)=\frac{\cos(\alpha_{1})+\cos(\alpha_{2})+...\cos(\alpha_{n})}{2}$$Moreover: $$\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}+...+\alpha_{n}=2\pi$$However I don't know how to use $S'(\alpha)$ to find polygons with largest area because I have sum of $n$ other $\cos$. Probably $\alpha_{1}=\alpha_{2}=...\alpha_{n}$ but I don't know how to prove it.
Do you have any tips on how to continue my plan?

Comment: The largest *field* ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using backward induction, we can prove that if $0<\alpha_i<\pi$ for $i=1,2,3\dots, n$, then

$$n\sin\frac{\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\cdots+\alpha_n}{n}\ge \sin \alpha_1+\sin\alpha_2+\cdots+\sin\alpha_n$$

with equalities holds if and only if $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\cdots=\alpha_n$.

This implies that regular polygons have the largest possible areas.

Answer (score 1):

With three points,

$$S:=\sin a+\sin b+\sin(\pi-a-b).$$

Then cancelling the derivative on both angles,
$$\cos a-\cos(\pi-a-b)=0,\\\cos b-\cos(\pi-a-b)=0.$$

One of the solutions is $a=b=\dfrac{2\pi}3.$

This easily generalizes.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand how I can use this fact for $n$ $\alpha_{i}$

Comment: @MP3129: are you serious ?